# What is the meaning of "gastric percolation" in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have checked all the definition entries for the words [percolation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/percolate) and [gastric](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stomach), yet I can't totally understand what "gastric percolation" means in the following sentence:

> Of more urgent concern is the **gastric percolation** that I am experiencing [[Reference]](https://books.google.com/books?id=rtK3qBHWg1wC&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=%22gastric%20percolation%22&source=bl&ots=9li8jXtr4c&sig=ACfU3U2YYPC5BgRTaPa8QaMqzzLIl8gntg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWrOCPqP7hAhWpnOAKHbcCDo0Q6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22gastric%20percolation%22&f=false).

Does it mean fullness of the stomach? That's the only meaningful interpretation that I can come up according to the dictionary entries.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=rtK3qBHWg1wC&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=%22gastric+percolation%22&source=bl&ots=9li8jXtr4c&sig=ACfU3U2YYPC5BgRTaPa8QaMqzzLIl8gntg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWrOCPqP7hAhWpnOAKHbcCDo0Q6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22gastric%20percolation%22&f=false

Comment: @jonathanjo Hello, Thanks for letting me know, I think it should work now.

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down-vote a question, that helps everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, **gastric percolation** means "the filtering through the stomach" and he is using it to mean he has **diarrhoea**.

The writing is describing it very delicately, but the link shows key words "continence", "sputtering" and "toilet paper".  "Could I get sick from a tiny residue of bad water?"

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now. I just read two sentences after this sentence and stopped and asked this question.

Comment: It really just means "stomach movements" but the following description makes it clear what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

"Gastric percolation" is simply a colorful way to describe his abdominal discomfort due to persistent diarrhea.  We can imagine he feels an internal sensation akin to the sound of *percolating* coffee -- a constant -- and increasingly urgent -- bubbling and rumbling in his belly.

Anatomically speaking, this is actually happening in the author's *colon*, not his stomach, so it should be *colonic* or *intestinal* percolation. [*Gastric*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gastric) specifically refers to the stomach, not the entire digestive system ... but I suppose we can forgive the author's lack of medical accuracy.